# Surface temperature of the sun if we were to watch it with naked eyes?

Tags: astronomy

If we were to safely watch our sun in high noon with naked eyes, like what we can do during the last moment of the sunset, what should be the surface temperature of the sun?

Comment: The "safe" viewing region does not have an accepted definition.  Some may even argue that it is always unsafe.  Is it reasonable to treat your question as the very specific one "what surface temperature of the sun would permit the same level of safety as observing our sun (at its real temperature) as it is setting?"  That would avoid any safety questions.

Comment: It Sun was farther away, or just less luminous, we could observe it safely at the same surface temperature.

Comment: VTH as unclear what you're asking.  What do you mean by "safe?"  Are you asking about heat transfer?  Luminosity?  Spectrum?  Please realize this will likely affect what you're really looking for, which might not be the sun's surface temperature.

Comment: The question seems to be based on some fundamental misunderstandings.  The sun doesn't really have a surface (it's gas/plasma), and it's temperature certainly doesn't vary during an Earth day.  The difference between its intensity at noon and sunset is due to the amount of Earth's atmosphere (and dust, haze, clouds, &c) the light travels through.  Consider the noontime sun seen through moderate clouds, with just a pale disk showing...

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere around 5000-5400 K (as opposed to the Sun's effective surface temperature of ~5700K) would probably do it. Such a star would be straddling the dividing line between G-class "yellow dwarfs" (they aren't yellow) and K-class "orange dwarfs", and would probably hover somewhere around 60% or 70% of the Sun's luminosity (= light output, or close enough for government work) depending on a variety of factors. However, if you just replaced the Sun with an orange dwarf the Earth would freeze, so there's that.

It's also worth pointing out that staring at the Sun is dangerous because our ancestors never had to evolve structures that would allow them to do so. This being worldbuilding and not astronomy, it's perfectly conceivable for a species to have developed the ability to stare at a much, much brighter star than the Sun, even, if they had a *reason* to.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about temperature.

What hurts when you look at the sun - or even its reflection - is the ultraviolet radiation your eyes are getting. When the sun is low on the horizon, a good deal of that radiation is refracted away - it's the same mechanism that tints the sky red. But there is still enough UV coming from the sun to damage your eyes, **so do not look at the sun when it is setting, neither directly nor through filters**.

If you do wish, as an worldbuilding exercise, to make the sun colder so that it produces less UV rays... Just wait until it becomes a cold white dwarf, or even a black dwarf. But then it will probably not emit enough light for you to see anything, anyway.

Comment: Spectrum is closely related to temperature; the color we see strongly implies the colors we don't.

Comment: "nor through filters" - most filters will cut UV to a safe level.

Comment: Given [this meta discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate?cb=1), this answer was premature (and is frankly a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @Alexander I agree that the reference to UV probably needs to be cited, but there was indeed a major debacle during the 2017 eclipse with filters that were being sold as solar glasses but did not meet standards.  Of course, there the primary issue was dealing with *both* UV and IR.  Some of these glasses were insufficient in one or the other, while still blocking visual light so you didn't know you were burning your retina until it was too late.